# Input attribute pattern does'nt work on IOS devices

Tags: html, forms, validation, input

The attribute `pattern` is not working without `required` and the `required` attribute is not yet compatible with the IOS devices.

I'm having trouble with minlength because it's not working on my code but maxlength works fine. I can't use oninvalid because I'm using a dynamic form and as well as jquery validate.

Any thoughts or recommendations?

```html
<form method="post">
  <input type="text" required pattern=".{3,}">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c7v7zbw6/)